# how to receive message from mediator in hyperledger aries

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, messaging

I want to receive basic-message from the mediator in hyperledger aries while sending message to mediator is done and working fine. Any kind of help regarding this topic will  be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment i'm only aware of the basic message protocol (https://github.com/hyperledger/aries-rfcs/tree/master/features/0095-basic-message), which is a very simple protocol allowing two agents to exchange messages. You could build a simple chat application using this protocol. Because this protocol is so simple, it is implemented in almost all aries frameworks. However if you want to build a robust chat application you would probably be better of creating a new protocol which explicitly adds support for things such as read receipts, emoji-responses group messages, and other things as listed in the out of scope section of the basic message protocol (https://github.com/hyperledger/aries-rfcs/tree/master/features/0095-basic-message#out-of-scope)